# Matlab Replacing Loop with Range Expression

Tags: matlab, for-loop, replace, range

I have function called `buildRay` which returns a 1x4 matrix. I call it multiple times like so:

```
rays = zeros(numRays, 4);
for j = 1:numRays
    rays(j, :) = buildRay(particle, (j-1)*anglePart, rayLength);
end
```

If I try and replace the loop with:

```
rays(1:numRays, :) = buildRay(particle, ((1:numRays)-1).*anglePart, rayLength);
```

I get the following error

> ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

and I don't understand why.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message state, your left and right expressions have different size. You cannot do it in MATLAB.

To avoid for-loop you can use ARRAYFUN function:

```
rays = arrayfun(@(x) buildRay(particle, ((x-1).*anglePart, rayLength), 1:numRays);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted.

Comment: Arrayfun is slower than the for loop!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change buildRays to accept a vector (or matrix) of input arguments and return a matrix sized appropriately (i.e. not always `1x4` - if the input vector is `N` elements, return an `Nx4` matrix).

Right now, you're trying to assign a `1x4` vector into a `numRays x 4` spot - hence the error.